# I want to reload a webpage in a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reload

I want to reload a page in loop but the issue is when I just put reload in an infinite loop it starts reloading but never finish a single reload.
So, I used `setTimeout` but, it reloads page only once and console also get reloaded.

```
function reload_p() {
  window.location.reload(1);
}

let n = 3;
while (n--) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    reload_p();
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to reload the whole page multiple times? Keep in mind that `setTimeout` will be triggered brandnew on reloading the page

Comment: I put the above code in browser developer console but this reload only once.

Answer (score 2):

You can use session

```
if(!sessionStorage.getItem('counter')) {
   sessionStorage.setItem('counter', 3);
}

let n = sessionStorage.getItem('counter');

if(n !== 0) { 
   window.location.reload(1);
} else {
   sessionStorage.removeItem('counter');
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about using localStore, or storing the variable as a url parameter as an alternative, but using session definitely makes more sense.